# Trying to populate a database table from a php loop

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I am trying to populate a database table with over 1,000 rows of data (random generated numbers).
My code:

```
$input = new Card($request->all());
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 1000 ){
        $input->pin = intval( "2" . rand(100,999) . rand(10000,99999) );
        $input->save();
        $i++;
    }
```

The problem is that only one data is sent to the database.
I also tried this `for` loop too with:

```
$input = new Card($request->all());
    for($i=1; $1<= 1000;$i++ ){
        $input->pin = intval( "2" . rand(100,999) . rand(10000,99999) );
        $input->save();
    }
```

And the same problem, only one row affected.

Comment: The problem is probably in that function or class.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your Card class, but I might suspect that using dot instead of comma in intval( "2" . rand(100,999) . rand(10000,99999) ) might be a factor here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are saving the same `Card` each time, not creating new.

Try the following...

```
for ($i=1; $1<= 1000; $i++) {
    $card = Card::newInstance($request->all());
    $card->pin = intval( "2" . rand(100,999) . rand(10000,99999) );
    $card->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was the problem. Once I tried yours it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for something like the following approach:

```
    $password = Hash::make('secret');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
    {
        $users[] = [
            'email' => 'user'. $i .'@myapp.com',
            'password' => $password
        ];
    }

    User::insert($users);
```

This will also drastically improve performance.